# javax.validation not working when noargsconstructor is used

Tags: java, validation, lombok

I am trying to validate a request object, whose class is as follows:

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeCreateRequest {
    @NotNull(message = "Name can not be null")
    @NotBlank(message = "Name can not be empty")
    String name;
}
```

Without NoArgsConstructor, validation works but POST operation fails with HttpMessageNotReadableException; with NoArgsConstructor, POST operation succeeds but validation doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. using Java 8, Spring 2.3.4.RELEASE, javax.validation 2.0.1.Final and my controller looks like below:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

    private final MyService myService;

    @PostMapping()
    public MyResponse submit(@Valid @RequestBody SomeCreateRequest request){
        return myService.create(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using `@Valid ` in the controller? be careful  `@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)` with this, because Jackson deserializer needs a no args constructor, can you put an example of your controller annotations that you are using?

Comment: Yes I am using @Valid in my controller. See my edit on the question.

Comment: The object needs a no-args constructor to be created **or** JSON metadata to know which constructor to invoke. The fact that the validation isn't working is probably due to you added `javax.validation` as a dependency whereas you should have used `spring-boot-starter-validation`. The latter includes both the API **and** and implementation, adding only the API doesn't do a thing.